# Why does this integral have a complex component?

Tags: numerical-integration, complex, probability-or-statistics

I wanted to find the probability of my normally-distributed random variable being at least 15, so I set up this integral:

```
Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[14, 3.7], x], {x, 15, Infinity}]
```

Imagine my surprise when I got this result:

```
0.393476 - 1.75334*10^-15 I
```

Granted, the angle is miniscule. But why is Mathematica producing this result? This happens even if I type in the PDF manually:

```
0.107822 E^(-0.036523 (-14 + x)^2)
```

My TI in rectangular mode returns a result equal to the real component of what Mathematica produces. No complex component.

It doesn't make sense for a real-valued function to have complex area anyway. What's going on here? Whenever I see e's and i's in the same room I tend to blame Euler, but I'm having trouble figuring out what Mathematica is doing.

Using the "proper" Mathematica command for computing this probability returns a value that agrees with my calculator.

```
Probability[15 <= x, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[14, 3.7]]
```

I just want to know why Mathematica thinks the integral has complex area.

Comment: Those complex components are effectively 0's. Along with the e's and i's, you can now blame Old MacDonald. The actual issue is that `Integrate` can do"interesting" things when one mixes approximate numbers with what is really a set of symbolic methods. `NIntegrate`, being more appropriate for numeric functionality, will not give this imaginary fuzz.

Comment: A nice solution is given at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72714/how-to-prevent-tiny-complex-errors-in-integrate?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at 5 cases. Conclusion at bottom.

```
ClearAll[x, a, b];
pdf = PDF[NormalDistribution[14, 3.7], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
a0 = pdf[[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
b0 = pdf[[2, 2, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Case 1

```
int1 = Integrate[ a Exp[b (-14 + x)^2], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
int1 /. {a -> a0, b -> b0}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Simplify[(int1 /. x -> Infinity) - (int1 /. x -> 15)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Case 2

```
 int2 = Integrate[ a Exp[b (-14 + x)^2], {x, 15, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 int2 /. {a -> a0, b -> b0}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Case 3

```
 int3 = Integrate[ a Exp[b (-14 + x)^2] /. {a -> a0, b -> b0}, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Simplify[(int3 /. x -> Infinity) - (int3 /. x -> 15)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Case 4

```
 int4 = Integrate[a Exp[b (-14 + x)^2] /. {a -> a0, b -> b0}, {x, 15, k}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Limit[int4, k -> Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Case 5

```
 int5 = Integrate[a Exp[b (-14 + x)^2] /. {a -> a0, b -> b0}, {x, 15, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Chop[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Conclusion

The error can be `Chopped`. Complex number show up due the function `Erfi` which comes due to the term `exp[x^2]` in the integrand as you can see from above

```
 Expand[(-14 + x)^2]  (* 196 - 28 x + x^2 *)
 Integrate[Exp[x^2], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So this answers the question as to where does the complex number comes from. For example, a complex number can show up like this:

```
  Erfi[Sqrt[b] ] /. b -> b0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a general point, it is best to delay as long as possible using floating point values in expressions, and substitute these at the very end to get the "most" accurate result. As you can see from the cases above, when the numbers are substituted at the end, less "noise" was present in the intermediate result.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a couple of more observations to [Nasser's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser).

### Case 6

As [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) hints at in a comment, if we use an exact `37/10` in place of the approximate `3.7`, we get an exact result with a zero imaginary component:

```
Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[14, 37/10], x], {x, 15, Infinity}]
N@%
(*
  1/2 Erfc[(5 Sqrt[2])/37]
  0.393476
*)
```

### Case 7

Such a small imaginary component suggests it is due to round-off error.  If it is, then using arbitrary precision numbers, say `` 3.7`16 ``, instead of [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision.html) numbers, e.g. `3.7`, usually produces a zero component.

```
Integrate[PDF[NormalDistribution[14, 3.7`16], x], {x, 15, Infinity}]
(*
  0.3934761677149 + 0.*10^-15 I
*)
```

The zero imaginary component may be removed with `Chop` as `Nasser` points out.