# Numerical integration over Re[expr] still has $0 i$ in the result

Tags: numerical-integration, complex

I am using `NIntegrate` to evaluate the integral of the *real part* of some function.

```
nbs1 = {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 0}};
A1 = 0.6049; l = 3 A1 + 10^-3;
gap[k_] := A1*Sum[Exp[-2 π I k . nb], {nb, nbs1}];
en[k_] := Sqrt[l^2 - Abs[gap[k]]^2]; 
fg[k_] := gap[k]/(l + en[k]);

NIntegrate[Re[fg[{kx, ky}] Exp[2 π I (kx + ky)]],
 {kx, -0.5, 0.5}, {ky, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

However, the result is `0.014725 + 0. I`, still carrying a complex part although it is identically zero, and I also get the message *"Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small"*.

But the integrand is *explicitly real* (by the function `Re`; this contrasts some old posts like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115906/74485) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37056/74485) one), and I am using `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate`. So I wonder what produces this `+ 0. I` (how Mathematica calculate the integral under the hood), and how I can get rid of it during the integration and possibly improve the evaluation speed.

Comment: You can just `Chop` the integral result to get rid of the `+ 0. I`. You can also `ComplexExpand` the integrand, although this does make the integration take longer:

`int = Re[fg[{kx, ky}] Exp[2 \[Pi] I (kx + ky)]] // ComplexExpand;`
`NIntegrate[int, {kx, -0.5, 0.5}, {ky, -0.5, 0.5}]` `(*0.014725*)`

The `NIntegrate` warnings still persist however

Comment: I am aware of these methods; however, I want to know more on how Mathematica do my integral under the hood.

Comment: Ah ok. For what it's worth, explicitly stating the `Method` as `Method -> "LocalAdaptive"` seems to remove this problem, while `Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"` has the `+0. I` part and the warning messages.

Comment: `Re[NIntegrate[
  Re[fg[{kx, ky}] Exp[2 \[Pi] I (kx + ky)]], {kx, -0.5, 
   0.5}, {ky, -0.5, 0.5}]]` ?

Comment: Use `A1 = 0.6049 // Rationalize;` and `NIntegrate[Re[fg[{kx, ky}] Exp[2 \[Pi] I (kx + ky)]], {kx, -1/2, 1/2}, {ky, -1/2, 1/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 15, MinRecursion -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 20] `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Overview

1. The problem arises in the compiled function created for some sort of singularity processing that `NIntegrate[]` decided was necessary.
2. Is it a bug? Ask WRI. Here are two things to consider. (a) The singularity processing is not necessary. (b) The compiled function created has a return type `Complex` even though the function is `Real`. The function being compiled is derived from the integrand and is slightly more complicated (a linear combination of `Re[]` expressions). `Compile[]` seems to gives up on the analysis of this function and defaults to the safer type `Complex` for the result.
3. The comments show some ways to avoid a complex output. A direct fix is to turn off the singularity handler:

```
NIntegrate[
 Re[fg[{kx, ky}] Exp[2 \[Pi] I (kx + ky)]],
  {kx, -0.5, 0.5}, {ky, -0.5, 0.5},
 MinRecursion -> 1, (* stops the GlobalAdaptive slow-con warning *)
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None}]
(*  0.014725  *)
```

#### Analysis

Here's how to analyze the integration.  [`IntegrationMonitor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26401/determining-which-rule-nintegrate-selects-automatically/96663#96663) returns information about the integral over each subregion.

```
NIntegrate[
 Re[fg[{kx, ky}] Exp[2 \[Pi] I (kx + ky)]],
 {kx, -0.5, 0.5}, {ky, -0.5, 0.5},
 IntegrationMonitor :> ((foo = #) &)]
```

Pick out the subregions over which the integral is complex:

```
Position[Through[foo["Integral"]], _Complex]
cplx = Extract[foo, %];
(*
{{137}, {138}, {139}, {140}, {141}, {142}, {146}, {147}, {148}, \
{149}, {150}, {155}, {156}, {327}, {328}, {333}, {336}, {337}, {338}, \
{339}, {342}, {344}, {346}, {347}, {348}, {349}}
*)
```

Each subregion has an `` Experimental`NumericalFunction[] `` used to evaluate the integral, and the numerical function has a `CompiledFunction` (in the OP's case).  Unsurprisingly, the ones related to `Real` integral values have `Real` integrand values, and those with `Complex` integral values have `Complex` integrand values.

```
nfR = foo[[1]]["NumericalFunction"];
cfR = nfR@"CompiledFunction";

nfC = cplx[[1]]["NumericalFunction"];
cfC = nfC@"CompiledFunction";

nfR[-0.375`, -0.375`]
cfR[-0.375`, -0.375`]
(*
-0.125894
-0.125894
*)

nfC[0.96875`, 1.]
cfC[0.96875`, 1.]
(*
0.00102451 + 0. I
0.00102451 + 0. I
*)
```

We can check that the return type agrees with the results (a redundant step).

```
Needs@"CompiledFunctionTools`"

Cases[ToCompiledProcedure[cfR], _CompiledResult, Infinity]
(*  {CompiledResult[Register[Real, 2]]}  *)

Cases[ToCompiledProcedure[cfC], _CompiledResult, Infinity]
(*  {CompiledResult[Register[Complex, 17]]}  *)
```

One can examine the end of the output of `CompilePrint@cfR` and `CompilePrint@cfC` to see that both apply `Re[]` etc. The output is rather long, and I will omit it. One can also see whether the result is a real or complex register.

We can test the hypothesis that it is `Compile` that fails to parse the `Real` value of the function:

```
testC = Compile[{{kx, _Complex}, {ky, _Complex}},
  Evaluate@nfC@"FunctionExpression"]
testC[0.96875`, 1.]
(*  0.00102451 + 0. I  *)
```

Here's the form of the function in `nfC[]`:

```
Shallow[nfC@"FunctionExpression", 5]
(*  kx (0.00236289 Re[<<1>>] + 0.00236289 Re[<<1>>])  *)
```

Clearly, one wants the time `Compile[]` spends analyzing code to be very short, especially in auto-compiled code. It's hard to argue strongly that it is a bug. Normally, if the user is calling `Compile[]` there are workarounds. I don't know of any hooks in `NIntegrate[]` to control `Compile[]`.